# selenium webdriver - xpath locator not working if element's text contains Unicode Characters

Tags: selenium, xpath, unicode, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to select an option contained inside a menu.  It's not a select menu, but it's styled to appear as such.  Anyway, if the text contained inside the menu is in English, I can select it ok.  Trouble is, the text I need to select is french so it contains the letter "c" with a cedilla.  Webdriver can't seem to recognize it.  Am I missing something here?  Here is a code sniplet:

```
<div id="Language"><span class="combobox"><input name="" type="text" autocomplete="off" label="" placeholder="" class=""><span class="combobox-button" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">▼</span><div class="menu menu-vertical" role="menu" aria-haspopup="true" style="-webkit-user-select: none; left: 392px; top: 107px; display: none;"><div class="menuitem" role="menuitem" id=":15" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="menuitem-content">Français</div></div></div></span></div>
```

I'm using an xpath locator to get the element by the text so I'm trying this with no joy:

```
Iwebelement FrenchOption = driver.findelement(By.XPath("//div[text()='Français']"));
```

This xpath locator works fine to find english text.  I have resulted to finding the element by ID which works fine but the element ID's will change so I would like to get this working so I don't have to keep changing the ID's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing something here?

Yes, I think so:

```
<div class="menuitem-content">Français</div>
```

the "a" is missing

```
driver.findelement(By.XPath("//div[text()='Françis']"));
```

EDIT:

At least in a Java environment Webdriver **can** handle Unicode. this works for me (driver in this case being an instance of `FirefoxDriver`):

```
driver.get("https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mot%C3%B6rhead");
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h1[contains(., Motörhead)]"));
 System.out.println(driver.getTitle() + " is showing " + we.isDisplayed());
```

prints out:

> Motörhead — Wikipédia is showing true

So, if you have trouble with encoding, it is probably due to encoding of your source files.

The fact that you made the typo hints on that as well. If you copy and paste unicode characters across different encodings, the result is unpredictable. In this case (just guessing) the cedilla, due to bad transformation, may have eaten the "a".

Comment: Sorry I made a typo.  I haven't actually spelt it wrong

Comment: Thank you.  My issue was nothing to do with unicode characters.  Your reply actually lead me to find the reason why.  Essentially, I had another menu hidden on another form inside my web app.  Debugging provided no clue of this.  It was only when I used a third party xpath checker tool that I realized I had two elements of the same, so my xpath locator was picking up the wrong one.